# How do I refresh ViewController after dismiss method is called

Tags: swift, xcode

For example, I have two viewControllers named A and B. I move to "B view controller" after present method is called. I set some values through UserDefaults.stnadard on "B viewController", and I come back to "A view controller" after dismiss method is called. "A viewController" have to show modified values, but it doesn't show the modified ones. I tried calling `viewDidAppear()` method on "A viewController", but it didn't work. I tried calling `viewDidLoad()` method, and it worked well, but I heard that it's not a good way to call the method directly. System can only call it. So, I don't want to call it myself. How should I refresh "A view controller"?

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 13.0 and above, Apple has changed the way viewControllers are presented by default. So, **viewWillAppear** in ViewControllerA will not be called after dimissing ViewControllerB.

One way for making sure the **viewWillAppear** method will be called after dismissing ViewControllerB is presenting the viewController setting modalPresentationStyle to fullScreen as:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Sample Code:

**ViewControllerA.swift**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    private var username: String? {
        UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USERNAME")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(username) //set this to desired view
    }

    @IBAction func goToViewControllerB(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerB.swift**

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserDefaults.standard.set("John", forKey: "USERNAME")
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the modalPresentationStyle to fullScreen then you can use closures for passing data to ViewControllerA when you're dismissing ViewControllerB.

Comment: 1) Is this true for non-swift as well?   Where is this discussed on Apple?

Answer (score 2):

I think NotificationCenter or prototype would help get this done.

> **NotificationCenter example**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testFunc), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:  "PeformAfterPresenting"), object: nil)

    }

    @objc func testFunc() {
      //TODO: your task
    }
}
```

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "PeformAfterPresenting"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's simple and works perfectly. ViewControllerA is able to react on various changes in ViewControllerB.

Answer (score 0):

A solid way to handle this would be to set up a protocol & delegate, and call it on ViewControllerB's viewWillDisappear.

In ViewControllerB, set up protocol and delegate property:

```
protocol ViewControllerBDelegate: AnyObject {
    func refreshUserDefaults()
}

weak var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate?
```

Also in ViewControllerB, call the method in viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.delegate?.refreshUserDefaults()
}
```

Then in ViewControllerA, before you present ViewControllerB, assign ViewControllerA as delegate:

```
let vc = ViewControllerB()
vc.delegate = self
// present as desired
```

Also in ViewControllerA, conform to ViewControllerB's protocol:

```
extension ViewControllerA: ViewControllerBDelegate {
    func refreshUserDefaults() {
        // do whatever you need here
    }    
}
```